# How to truncate only given column length?

Tags: sed, awk

INPUT:

```
a@notebook:~$ cat in.csv
'XYZ843141'^'ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg sdGDS  dsGDSgfa assfd faSDFAS saDFSAFD adFSA343fa sdfSADF'^'BAAAR'^'YYY'^'..... and so on, further columns
'YYZ814384'^'ASfdEtRiuognfnseaFREQTzKb   aSFfdsaADSFSA  adsFdsa34 34 ASFfsas  saftrzj etrzrasdfasffasf safs'^'foooobaaar'^'ZZZ'^'..... and so on, further columns
```

OUTPUT:

```
a@notebook:~$ cat in.csv | SOMEMAGIC
'XYZ843141'^'ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg s'^'BAAAR'^'YYY'^'..... and so on, further columns
'YYZ814384'^'ASfdEtRiuognfnseaFRE'^'foooobaaar'^'ZZZ'^'..... and so on, further columns
```

**My question**: If:

```
'^'
```

is the separator, then how can SOMEMAGIC (an awk/sed??) truncate the second column to given length? Example: 20 chars max, from this:

```
ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg sdGDS  dsGDSgfa assfd faSDFAS saDFSAFD adFSA343fa sdfSADF
```

to this:

```
ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg s
```

and preserve all the other things :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> awk -v OFS="'^'" -F"'\\\\^'" '{if(length($2)>20) $2=substr($2,1,20); print;}' file
'XYZ843141'^'ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg s'^'BAAAR'^'YYY'^'..... and so on, further columns
'YYZ814384'^'ASfdEtRiuognfnseaFRE'^'foooobaaar'^'ZZZ'^'..... and so on, further columns
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple sed example to get only 20 caracters from our string:

```
$ str = "ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg sdGDS  dsGDSgfa assfd faSDFAS saDFSAFD adFSA343fa sdfSADF"

$ echo $str | sed -e 's/^\(.\{20\}\).*/\1/'
ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg s
```

Or with **cut** command:

```
$ echo $str | cut -c 1-20
```

EDIT:
How about this :

```
$ echo $str | awk -F "^" '{print $1,$2}'
'XYZ843141' 'ASDFSAFXYVFSHGDSDg s'
```

Comment: now we only have to do this to the second column of a string, as in the example :\

Comment: simple and perfect thanks! `cat file.txt |cut -c 1-$(tput cols)`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
paste -d^ <(cut -f1 -d^ in.csv) \
          <(cut -f2 -d^ in.csv | sed -e 's/^\(.\{21\}\).*/\1'\''/')\
          <(cut -f3- -d^ in.csv)
```

However this will fail if there is `^` in some of the fields.